# Проблемы при упаковке файлов в архив

Tags: c#, zip

Есть папка с файлами и подпапками, в которой тоже хранятся файлы. Файлы обрабоатываюстя и по завершению, я хочу всю папку с содержимым поместить в zip. Смотрю, что можно воспользоваться методами в этом пространстве имен System.IO.Compression.ZipFile. Пожалуйста, кто уже работал, подскажите, какие проблемы могут быть? на что обратить внимание? любой совет ценен - спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Сходу могу предположить несколько проблем

- Место на диске кончится в процессе архивирования
- Файл, который архивируется, открыт другим процессом эксклюзивно
- Слишком длинное имя файла (с путём)
- Нехватка памяти

В целом я бы использовал схему инкрементального архивирования

1. Создали архив
2. Добавили файл
3. Добавили файл

и т.д. Так вы точно получите хоть какой-то результат, если вас устраивает подобный исход